# Select predefined variable using string returned from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, handlebars.js, ecmascript-5

I was wondering, whether this was even possible:
I have a webpage with a URL along the lines of this: ".../product.html?id1",

and using **Handlebars.js** I am trying to render from a js file with products:

```
$(function() {
  var id1 = {
    name: "Module 14/88",
    ID: "445856",
    desc: "some text"
  };
  var id2 = {
    name: "Kolp-display",
    ID: "445857",
    desc: "some other text"
  };
  //..... // about 60 more, but the same format
  function prid() {
    var full_url = document.URL;
    var url_array = full_url.split('?');
    var last_segment = url_array[url_array.length - 1];
    return last_segment;
  };

  var theTemplateScript = $("#template").html();
  var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
  $(".panel").append(theTemplate(prid())); // this does not work
});
```

And the template is embedded into HTML and works when I set the variable manually. It always renders just one product at a time, like a product page.

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2><span>{{name}}</span></h2>
        <p><span>{{ID}}</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2rem">
            <div class="col-sm-7 ">
                <p>{{desc}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

So essentially, I am trying to select a variable to be rendered (appended) from the id in URL, to be included in the part of:

```
$(".panel").append(theTemplate(___selected_variable_from_id_in_URL___));
```

So the value returned by **prid()** in this case is id1, and so I want the id1 array to be used by Handlebars.
As the variable is alredy defined, I just want to use the string from the **prid()** function as an identifier for the variable.
Is there a way to do this, I do not know and search has so far not been helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `eval` based on the code that you have currently.

The preferred approach would be is to have your entire data set as part of a single object, where `id` would be the keys and the, data the corresponding id's values.

```
var data = {
  id1: {
    name: "Module 14/88",
    ID: "445856",
    desc: "some text"
  },
  id2: {
    name: "Kolp-display",
    ID: "445857",
    desc: "some other text"
  }
};
```

Then you would just have to do `data[prop()]` to pull in the right data set.

Other other approach which I do not recommend is storing the variables as part of the window object or using eval.

**Accessing object from the global scope**

```
// or declare them in the global scope, which can then be accessed 
// from the same object
window.id1 { name:"Module 14/88", ID:"445856", desc:"some text" };
window.id2 { name:"Kolp-display", ID:"445857", desc:"some other text" };

window[prop()]
```

This can introduce variable leaks in the global namespace. It is always better to avoid using global variables.

**Using eval**

```
eval(prop())
```

Comment: Thanks. The first is probably the best option, changing the data set is easy enough.